# Using Rspec, how can I test a method which calls a method from another class in ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

My Transaction class has a method 'balance' which calls a method 'balance_after' from my Account class. I would like to make a test where I can check the 'balance_after' method is being called with the 'balance' method. I am new to both ruby and testing, so I appreciate any guidance! I am using simple-cov to get my coverage and i'd like to hit 100% if possible. I hope I have provided enough information. Thanks in advance!

```
Failures:

  1) Transaction#balance checks balance
     Failure/Error: @account.balance_after(self)
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `balance_after' for :account:Symbol
     # ./lib/transaction.rb:11:in `balance'
     # ./spec/transaction_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.04089 seconds (files took 0.87223 seconds to load)
10 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/transaction_spec.rb:18 # Transaction#balance checks balance


COVERAGE:  98.55% -- 68/69 lines in 4 files

+----------+--------------------+-------+--------+---------+
| coverage | file               | lines | missed | missing |
+----------+--------------------+-------+--------+---------+
|  90.91%  | lib/transaction.rb | 11    | 1      | 16      |
+----------+--------------------+-------+--------+---------+
```

My Transaction class

```
class Transaction
  attr_reader :amount, :account, :timestamp

  def initialize(amount, account)
    @amount = amount
    @account = account
    @timestamp = Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
  end

  def balance
    @account.balance_after(self)
  end

  def formate
    @amount > 0 ? (puts "#{@timestamp}|| #{@amount} ||  ||  #{balance}")
    : (puts "#{@timestamp}||  || #{@amount.abs}  ||  #{balance}")
  end
end
```

My Account class

```
require_relative 'transaction'

class Account
  attr_reader :balance, :transactions

  HEADER = 'date || credit || debit || balance'

  def initialize
    @balance = 0
    @transactions = []
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    @balance += amount
    @transactions << Transaction.new(amount, self)
  end

  def withdraw(amount)
    @balance -= amount
    @transactions << Transaction.new(-amount, self)
  end

  def balance_after(transaction)
    index = @transactions.find_index(transaction)
    @transactions[0..index].map(&:amount).sum
  end

  def print_statement
    puts HEADER
    @transactions.reverse.map(&:formate)
  end
end
```

My Transaction spec

```
require 'transaction'

describe Transaction do
  let(:transaction) { Transaction.new(:amount, :account) }
  let(:timestamp) { Time.now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') }

  describe '#initilalize' do
    it 'validates class' do
      expect(transaction).to be_a Transaction
    end

    it 'stores dates' do
      expect(transaction.timestamp).to eq timestamp
    end
  end

  describe '#balance' do
    it 'checks balance' do
      expect(transaction.balance).to eq true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the method correctly. `Transaction.new` takes an amount, presumably a number, and some sort of Account object which has `balance_after` defined. You've given it two Symbols.

```
describe Transaction do
  let(:account) { Account.new }
  let(:amount) { 1.23 }
  let(:transaction) { Transaction.new(amount, account) }
  let(:timestamp) { Time.now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') }
```

Then check that it returns what you expect. `balance` does not return true or false, it returns a balance. Specifically, it's just a pass through to `account.balance_after(transaction)`, so test that.

```
  describe '#balance' do
    it 'checks balance' do
      expect(transaction.balance).to eq account.balance_after(transaction)
    end
  end
```

This might seem circular, but this is just an integration test. `account.balance_after` would be unit tested as part of Account's tests. There's no need to repeat those tests here.

Comment: Hey Schwern, thanks for the help! This got some more coverage which is lovely, but some lines are still missing apparently so ill assume it'll be solved once I test for the formate method in the Transaction class?. You mentioned that the balance method was not needed because it should be tested in the Account class. Will this apply to my formate method in Transactions because I have the print_statement in my Account class? Thanks again!

Comment: @byronmac You don't need to extensively test `Transaction#balance` because it's just a wrapper around `Accountt#balance_after` and that's better covered in the tests for `Account#balance_after`. You *do* need to test `Transaction#formate` because that's all code within `Transaction`. Look up "integration test" vs "unit test".

Comment: @byronmac BTW the code in `formate` can be simply `puts "#{@timestamp}||  || #{@amount.abs}  ||  #{balance}"`. The absolute value of a number is the same whether it's positive or negative.